# JPA + Hibernate + PostgreSQL - Left Join and Group By

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I just wondering how I can make in JPA with JPQL or Criteria builder a "LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY". I have as entity objects "User", "Questions" and "Answers". Lets assume I like to get a statistics about how many users has answered a specific question.

With JPA and SQL this would look like this

```
select x.value, count(u) from users u
left join (
   select a.* from answers a
   join questions q on q.id = a.question_id 
   where q.name = 'participation') as x on x.user_id = u.id
group by x.value

Query q = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);
List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();
```

which will produce a result like this

```
value       count
[NULL]      102      // users which have no answers
Yes         10
No          34
Perhaps     56
```

How can I achieve this with a JPQL or the CriteriaBuilder ?

Here my domain classes

```
@Entitiy
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
   @Id
   private Long id;
}

@Entitiy
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private Question question;

    private String value;
}

@Entitiy
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Comment: JPA doesn't do temporary tables. You will probably have to use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

Query might look like this

```
SELECT a.value, count(u.id) FROM User u LEFT JOIN Answer a ON a.user.id = u.id LEFT JOIN a.question q GROUP BY a.value;
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not consider the "null" values (when no user has provided an answer). It generates an SQL like this `select answer1_.value as col_0_0_, count(user0_.id) as col_1_0_ from users user0_ left outer join answers answer1_ on (answer1_.user_id=user0_.id) inner join questions question2_ on answer1_.question_id=question2_.id where question2_.name='participation' group by answer1_.value`.

Comment: Right, inner join on question does that. Try left joining it. I edited query.